# How to store CronTrigger information into repository and load TaskScheduler as application start up?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a scheduling application where user defines some jobs to be run at specified timing. When the job is triggered it should call a RESTFUL URL. Also such jobs have attributes like number of retries and timeout settings as well. I am blocked at two points:

1. The `CronTrigger` is represented and stored into database as string but question is how can I convert it to a `CronTrigger` which is used later to create `TaskScheduler`?
2. The application should read all information from repository from database and build `TaskScheduler` at startup but I don't know how to achieve this.

Entity

```
@Entity
public class ScheduledJob {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String cronTrigger;
    private String URL;
    private int numRetries;
    private int timeout;
}
```

Comment: Instead of inventing your own solution use Quartz with a persistent store.

Comment: Thanks but 1. can you please move your comment as an answer so that I could mark it as a solution. 2. do you have any suggestions regarding my question 2?

Comment: If you use Quartz 2 is for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to cobble together your own solution I suggest to use the [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) instead. With Spring Boot (2 or higher) that is even more simple as support for Quartz has been added (see the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-quartz)).

Quartz  has out-of-the-box support for storing that kind of information in the database. It will use that information to trigger jobs as well. Which basically gives you 1 and 2 for free.

Drawback is that you have to use something other then `@Scheduled` to schedule your jobs.